# Display the most popular male and female names

Tags: sql, select, mariadb, aggregate-functions

**Display the most popular male and female names from the year 1983 from the database named BabyName**

```
SELECT COUNT(name) "Most Popular M/F Names from 1983", name  
FROM BabyName 
GROUP BY name 
ORDER BY year = '1983' AND COUNT(name) DESC
LIMIT 50
```

This is trying to pull the most popular male and female names from the year 1983. This is using a database called babyname and its a fairly large database.
This is the only way I figured out but I also feel like its wrong because its asking for the most popular female and male names. Any suggestions on how you might approach this? I can't show the DB information because its fairly large but it contains the name, gender, year they were born and the place they are from.

Comment: Why does your included query not meet the requirements? Are you looking for the top 50 most popular names for males and top 50 most popular names for females?

Comment: I want the most popular name for male and then female, but i get a list of them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MariaDB you can use window functions:

```
with cte as (
    select
        gender,
        name,
        count(*) as c,
        dense_rank() over (partition by gender order by count(*) desc) as dr
    from babyname
    where year = 1983
    group by gender, name
)
select *
from cte
where dr <= 5
order by gender, c desc
```

Comment: So I am writing a sql script with .SQL extension and then running it on mariadb on UNIX. But it doesn't seem to work is there something i should change

Comment: Ask another question and provide all details (if you get any error message etc).